# Plone and Mysql Searching

Tags: mysql, plone, zope, ploneformgen

I have Mysql and Zope talking to each other nicely.
I can insert values in, and even view one record from the databse and have it show up in the form fields(not that cool really).

I have just been following tutorials, but now I need to search the Database and display the results.

I have been fiddling with this for a while but I haven't gotten far. 
I know that using a Zope Page template we can call the Zsql method and show the results with TAL, but I need to some how using a script and a redirect form the search form pass the search data.

Can anyone help we get started?

Can anyone show me a way to do it with formgen and a custom script adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your ZMI, and add a "Z Search Interface" object in the same folder as your ZSQL method.  Your ZSQL methods should show as "searchable objects".  Select the ZSQL method you want, fill in the rest of the fields, and it will generate form and display page templates.  Then modify the templates to taste.

Comment: The Z Search Interface is old Zope 2 stuff and does not integrate with Plone.

Comment: I'm not telling him how to make a complete application, I'm showing him how to build basic templates.  I've done this many times, modifying the resulting templates to use Plone's macros and integrate nicely.  If you want to go so far as to make Zope3 browser views, you can still use this as a base.

Comment: Can anyone show me a way to do it with formgen and a custom script adapter?